# <input> element inside <option> tag angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I am trying to put the `<input>` element inside the `<mat-option>` tag of the `<mat-select>` element in angular material. But it's not allowing me to write some text on the input inside select.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Group">
    <mat-option value="option">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Input">
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Above is what I did.

Comment: ASAP? `<input matInput (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" ` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yue7dz?file=app/select-overview-example.html

Comment: it worked fine. thankyou. :). ASAP- as soon as possible

Comment: I just wanted to say that ASAP sounds like demand:)

Comment: Even I- have same issue, but I tried with the above code, still it is not working